# Select item from Access DB

Tags: c#, ms-access, select

I'm searching for a row in a table in an Access DB. A field of the row has to be a specific value that the use inputs.

With

```cs
OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Job Control] where [Job No] like '%" + job_search_value + "%';", myConn);
```

I get data back, but everything that contains the value of `job_search_value`.
 What I need is the table row that has the field that is exactly `job_search_value`. The `[Job No]` field is `Int` and have tried

```cs
OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Job Control] where [Job No]=" + job_search_value + ";", myConn);
```

and

```cs
OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Job Control] where [Job No]=" + Convert.ToInt32(job_search_value) + ";", myConn);
```

With these 2 commands I don't get any error like `Data mismatch`, but don't get any data back either.

Answer (score 0):

you should and must use sql parameters for solving your issue as well as avoiding SQL injection. Try:

```
OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Job Control] where [Job No]=@param", myConn);
myQuery.Parameters.Add("@param"SQlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(job_search_value);
```